# Work Disutility Calibration

Tags: dsge

I'm trying to analytically calibrate the labor disutility parameter $\varphi_l$ in order to obtain the 0.33 value for labor at the steady state. However, I'm finding great difficulty in deriving the the parameter value since the FOC of labor is expressed in terms of the lagrangian multiplier $\lambda_t$ and wage $w_t$ which both are unknowns and aren't expressed in terms of other parameters. The author found 1.45 for $\varphi_l$, however I was unable to find the same value by myself. Can anyone please provide me with some help and guidance? Below are FOCs of the household and entrepreneur and tables containing the calibrated parameters and the steady states of the variables. Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]